# Express Routes & Controllers

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, express, ecmascript-6

I understand that out of the box Express isn't an MVC framework, however I'm trying to set it up like one.

I've used other similar frameworks in PHP like Laravel where in a route in you can use a controller like

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

Which will run all the code in the showProfile method in the UserController class,
so my question is, how would I achieve the same thing or something similar using Express?

I'm using Node 5 and writing the code in ECMAScript 6.

Currently I have a class I want to use as the controller and a method I want to return the data, I'm able to log the data to the console when a user navigates to the route but haven't figured out how to send it back as the response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js + Express: Routes vs controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076179/node-js-express-routes-vs-controller)

Answer (score 2):

If you dive into [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), you'll find that the "controller methods" you refer to need to conform to a specific signature. Namely, they receive (at least) the request and response representations.

If you have already created a [router](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router), this will be a rough equivalent to the PHP you posted:

```
router.get('user/profile', userController.showProfile)
```

Your showProfile "method" needs to have this signature:

```
const userController = {
  showProfile(req, res) { /*...*/}
}
```

I put "method" in quotes because express won't call it as a method unless you explicitly bind it to the controller object. We're passing it as an unbound function here. If you wanted to use it as a method (to have access to the controller as `this`), pass `userController.showProfile.bind(userController)` to `router.get`<sup>†</sup>.

But for now let's stick to those `req` and `res` parameters of the `showProfile` handler (that's the proper name). [`req`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) represents the HTTP request, you can get headers, request payload and other stuff from it. [`res`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) is the HTTP response that will be sent. So you can use it to set an HTTP status code, send body data and so on.

For illustrative purposes, let's assume you can get your user profile synchronously by calling `userController.getProfile(id)`. And let's assume that, by some mechanism, a property `userId` is set on the `req`uest that is the currently authenticated user's ID.

```
const userController = {
  showProfile(req, res) {
    // We call some code to get what we want to send back
    const profile = userController.getProfile(req.userId)
    // We send it in the response as JSON
    res.send(profile)
  }
}
```

`res.json` will JSON.stringify the profile and send it as response payload.

How do you get `req.userId` set, you ask? Well, this is just an example, but you can achieve similar results by using middleware. A middleware is simply a handler that does something and then lets other handlers continue processing the request. But again, there's plenty to read from the docs.

<sub>† It's usually not necessary though, since controllers tend to be singletons. You can simply access its properties by doing `userController.otherProperty`. Of course, you don't even need to define a handler as a method of a controller object, it can be a function that stands on its own.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

**usercontroller.js**

```js
class UserController() {
  constructor() {
    this.users = ['user1', 'user2'];
  }

  getUsers(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json(this.users);
  }
}

//router.js 
const port = 3000;
const app = express();


const _invoke = function(controller) {
  return function(req, res) {
    const [controllerClass, method] = controller.split('@')
    const className = require(controllerClass)
    const obj = new className
    obj[method](req, res)
  }
}

app.get('/get-users',
  _invoke('./controllers/UserController@getUsers'));

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).